# sequelize scope with concatted where

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, where-clause, scopes

The following works if not using a scope:

```
where = {};

  ...
case c: {
  where = Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), {
    like: '% John Doe %'
  })
}
Model.findAll({
  where: where
})
```

But not as a scope function:

```
scopes: {
  field: function (field, keyword = '%%') {
    let where = {};
    switch (field.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'id':
        where.id = {[Op.like]: keyword};
        break;
      case 'email':
        where.email = {[Op.like]: keyword};
        break;
      case 'name' :
        where = sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('concat', sequelize.col('first_name'), ' ', sequelize.col('last_name')), {
          [Op.like]: keyword
        });
      }
      return {
        where
      }
    },
  }
```

getting this error:

> Unknown column 'User.attribute' in 'where clause'

`console.log(where)`:

```
Where {
  attribute: Fn { fn: 'concat', args: [ [Col], ' ', [Col] ] },
  comparator: '=',
  logic: { [Symbol(like)]: '%%' }
}
```

has anyone tackled before?

Answer (score 0):

Is your scope function using "sequelize" when you need "Sequelize"?

```
...
case 'name' :
        where = Sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('first_name'), ' ', Sequelize.col('last_name')), {
          [Op.like]: keyword
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying
unfortunately it shows no difference... same error thrown

Comment: Check the syntax of the SQL that is being executed (if you've disabled logging, enable for this test).  What is the difference between SQL in your two cases?

Comment: Within scope: `Executing (default): SELECT 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at' FROM 'user' AS 'User' WHERE 'User'.'attribute' = concat('first_name', ' ', 'last_name') AND 'User'.'comparator' = '=' AND 'User'.'logic' LIKE '%test%';`

Comment: Outside scope:
`Executing (default): SELECT 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at' FROM 'user' AS 'User' WHERE concat('first_name', ' ', 'last_name') LIKE '%test%';
`

Comment: the difference is obvious... I'm still digging the correct method to concat within a scope. It seems to require a different approach

Comment: It might work without the .where() function -
`where =  { sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('first_name'), ' ',Sequelize.col('last_name')), {[Op.like]: keyword }
 };`  It isn't clear to me which circumstances require .where() - i have not done so in my apps.

Comment: Your proposal is not a valid javascript object as it is written.. It can be rephrased into `let full_name = sequelize.fn('concat', ...)` and then `where = {[full_name]: {[Op.like]: keyword}}` but that does not produce a valid result either: > Unknown column 'User.[object Object]'